# Parse not being called

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I have the code below that i want to loop through urls in a csv and for each url i want to run some selectors and return the data into a csv output. It seems to be looping through the start urls, but its raising an error saying that parse is not defined. i cant understand where i'm going wrong here. any help appreciated!

```
import scrapy
import csv

class CbdSitechekerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cbd_sitecheker'
    start_urls = []

    for url in open('sites.csv'):
        start_urls.append(url)

def start_requests(self):
    with open('sites.csv','r') as csvf:
        for url in csvf:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse_url)

def parse_url(self, response):
    links = response.xpath=('//a/@href').extract_first()
    yield {'links' : links}
```

Comment: remove the `self` from `parse_url`.

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for your input! I have tried removing the self from the "callback = self.parse_url" to leave "callback = parse_url", but i still get the error:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 80, in parse
    raise NotImplementedError('{}.parse callback is not defined'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
NotImplementedError: CbdSitechekerSpider.parse callback is not defined.

What am i missing? thanks

Comment: I imagine the issue involves the object referenced by `self` here. Because you are yielding an instance of `Request` -- `self` may very well refer to the `Request` class object itself. rather than the `CbdSitechekerSpider` class. Since Request doesn't have a method called `parse_url` you get the NotImplementedError.

Comment: I added an answer, let me know if that works? Also depending on your indentation, Guillermes answer could be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Check your indentation. The functions `start_requests` and `parse_url` need to be indented to the right, because right now they don't belong to your class.

```py
class CbdSitechekerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cbd_sitecheker'

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('sites.csv','r') as csvf:
            for url in csvf:
                yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse_url)

    def parse_url(self, response):
        links = response.xpath=('//a/@href').extract_first()
        yield {'links' : links}
```

Comment: thanks for the input Guillaume, i have tried indenting (in  configurations) but i get an error saying "unexpected indent...". I tried Josh's method too, but just nothing works. Totally lost here.

Comment: @nate_stack Please, see the edited answer, now with an example based on your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
def start_requests(self):
    parse_url = self.parse_url
    with open('sites.csv','r') as csvf:
        for url in csvf:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = parse_url)
```

This way the callback will be defined before you pass it into the Request initialize function.